# Does Oracle make recommendations for DML and ORMs?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

A coworker recently told me that Oracle recommends that DML should "live in the database", meaning that all inserts/updates/deletes should happen in packages and our application would only interact with the DB through these packages. Related to this, (maybe as a result of it), they also stated that Oracle officially recommends NOT using an ORM.

When I asked where these recommendations come from, they said "Oracle white papers". However I am unable find any official discussion of this topic from Oracle at all.

Does Oracle make official guidelines or recommendations regarding where DML should "live", and/or ORMs, (especially Hibernate)?

I'm not asking for anyone's opinion, just if anyone knows where to find this kind of documentation from Oracle so I can understand the argument here. It's definitely not part of their regular documentation but they may have published something on this topic somewhere else.

Comment: This is a question for https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/ :)

Comment: No.  You don't have to use any specific ORM with Oracle.  Hibernate is broadly compatible with all major RDBMS, with provisos and limitations on the more specific and off-standard stuff.  I think your friend is yanking your chain.  There are valid reasons not to use an ORM but the database vendor has no say in that decision.

Comment: The onus of proof is on them, really.  They're the ones spouting this.  They may be missing the point and purpose of ORMs altogether if they say that Oracle has recommendations for them.  If they can't prove it, then the company's architecture shouldn't be following them.  If they *do* wind up following that advice, take mine and look for a place that *doesn't* do that?

Comment: I'm not aware of an official policy. My rule is use SQL whenever you can. Use PL/SQL when that's not enough. Use the database to do work whenever possible bc it will be faster and safer. I've learned most of this from Tom of AskTom.

Comment: Check out support.oracle.com - Oracle officially supports Hibernate in at least some products: "How To Integrate Oracle Coherence With Hibernate? (Doc ID 455895.1)".  Database guys tend to dislike ORMs because we have to fight their lousy SQL statements.  But in 2017 it seems like a losing battle - applications have won, ginormous databases are dinosaurs.  (Maybe JOOQ would be a compromise?)

Comment: I have never seen such recomendations. If I were you, I would ask politely a colleague to give me some links for these whitepapers. I would say I was looking but could not find, so would he be so nice and give it to me.

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone. I suspected that the stated assertions were incorrect (or possibly very old and obsolete), but they were made by someone with authority who refused to explain but instead insisted I "look it up". So I am trying to make a good faith effort to do so. It is way too late in the project to make such a large architectural change, and starting to look like this person understands that, so this whole argument may turn out to have been moot.